# What properties were used to make this valid?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I would like to know what properties were used in making this answer?

$$\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt 2 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Because I am a bit clueless on the $\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\frac{\pi}4)$ was reached.

Comment: Note that $\sin \frac{\pi}{4}=\cos \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @Azzo That totally flew over my head.

Comment: And $\sin(x+y)=\sin x\cos y+ \cos x \sin y$

Comment: In fact there are many such rules involving trigonometric functions, see e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that for any $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sin (a+b) = \sin (a) \cos(b) + \sin(b) \cos(a)$. Also, $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. You have then

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin(x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4})\sin(x) + \sin(\frac{\pi}{4})\cos(x) = \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{4})$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sin(x+y)=\cos y \sin x  + \sin y \cos x$

Answer (score 1):

> $\sin(A+B)= sinA cosB + cosA sinB$

$\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt 2 \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x)+\frac{1}
{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)\right)$

=$\sqrt 2 \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin(x)+ \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\cos(x)\right)$

=$\sqrt{2}\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$